# How can I easily make printer-friendly pages of any website?

Tags: website, printing

I tried printing out a short story from http://www.americanliterature.com and it came out with huge margins.  The page is set up as a table with 3 columns.  The left and right ones have space for ads or menus, and the middle one has the text.  When I print it out it makes all the columns the same width.

Is there any easy way to get a printer-friendly version of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PrintFriendly.com](http://www.printfriendly.com/) exists for exactly this purpose. It looks great on [the first chapter of Moby Dick](http://www.printfriendly.com/print?url=http://www.americanliterature.com/Melville/MobyDickorTheWhale/2.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Printer Friendly](http://www.printfriendly.com/).  It seems to do the trick.