# How to print a 'print friendly' webpage?

Tags: printing, website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I easily make printer-friendly pages of any website?](https://superuser.com/questions/44946/how-can-i-easily-make-printer-friendly-pages-of-any-website)

is there a programme which prints or exports an image of a webpage without excluding backgrounds and other design aspects? a simple file>print does not include the background in most cases and tends to miss out a lot of the graphics. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Print out the page in question. Highlight everything you want to keep on the print-out in green. Mark elements that you don't want to keep in red.
- Create a new stylesheet document. Call it something like "print.css".
- Link your new stylesheet in the head section of your web page. It will look something like this:

  ```
  <link href="print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
  ```
- For each element of your page that you do not want printed, assign a class or id attribute in the HTML, if this is not already done. For example, if the site navigation is in a div tag, you might apply an id such as `<div id="nav">`.

  Note that an id must be unique within a document, but a class can apply to multiple elements.
- In print.css, put a corresonding instruction to not display the item. For example, if you don't want the navigation printed, write div#nav {display: none} into the print stylesheet.
- Use print.css to further define how the remaining printable items will appear. You can adjust positioning, page margins, typography, colors and more.

Comment: you do realise the whole point of this is very likely to save paper and ink. Quite honestly this is the most.. convoluted answer to the issue possible.

Comment: This sounds way more complicated than it needs to be. Also, check your formatting next time please.